# Not able to attach extracted POS taged Noun phrases to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am trying to extract only noun and noun phrases  to address data (a column a inside csv file).

I was able to  remove the stop words, punctuations and numbers from the data. Also  was able  POS tag the data, but not able Extract Noun Phrases and attach back to data frame. Let me know what went  wrong

```
    stopwords=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    user_defined_stop_words=['hong','kong','hk','kowloon','hongkong']                    
    new_stop_words=stopwords+user_defined_stop_words

    data['Clean_addr'] = data['Adj_Addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split()]))
    data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if  not  item.isdigit()]))
    data['Clean_addr']=data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x:"".join([item.lower() for item in x if item not in string.punctuation]))
    data['Clean_addr'] = data['Clean_addr'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split() if item not in (new_stop_words)]))

texts = data['Clean_addr'].tolist()
tagged_texts = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, texts))
data['POS']=tagged_texts
data['POS']=data['POS'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([item[0] for item in x if (item[0][1]=='NNP' or item[0][1]=='NNS')]))
```

Sample Dump of the File I am using

https://www.dropbox.com/s/allhfdxni0kfyn6/Test.csv?dl=0

Comment: Does it make sense to extract nouns from __addresses__? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `(item[0][1]=='NNP' or item[0][1]=='NNS')`? they are tuples and you are using a list comprehension, So just do `(item[1]=='NNP' or item[1]=='NNS')`

Comment: @MaxU, I am trying NNP

Comment: @Dark, It doesn't work, it simply appends the tags (NNS,NNP) to the dataframe. I want the words to be appended

Comment: Are you sure about that. I tried the code. And it indeed appended the words.

Comment: @Dark, Can you share your code as answer

Comment: @ShanyEapen ohk if you want there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data linked :

```
data['POS'].apply(lambda x : ','.join([i[0] for i in x if (i[1]=='NNS' or i[1] =='NNP')]))

0               des
1               des
2           cfa,des
3     registrations
4                  
5            floors
6            queens
7            queens
8            queens
9                  
10       solicitors
11                 
12                 
13                 
14                 
15              des
Name: POS, dtype: object
```

Comment: Haha, it happens. Good luck : )

Comment: maybe `i[1] in ['NNS','NNP']`?